# What's the most straightforward way to check Javascript Map equality?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two JavaScript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) objects, and I want to check their equality. What would be the most elegant way in JavaScript for that?

I'm using Angular for Typescript, so I'm also interested to hear Angular and Typescript solutions.

Comment: by two **javascript map objects** what do you mean?

Comment: @Aravind fixed the link, thanks for noticing!